# Fetching records from second table in one to many relationship produce error in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables, one is for approved projects and the other one is for artists details. i want to fetch data of "project name" data which is in the "project table" and "artists name" which is in the "artists table".

i have created the two relationships which are

ARTIST MODEL RELATIONSHIP

```
public function approved_relation()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\approved_projects_model', 'artist_id');
}
```

APPROVED MODEL RELATIONSHIP

```
 public function artists_relation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\artists_details_model', 'id');
}
```

In my controller, i have written the following code

```
$art_artist_details = approved_projects_model::with('artists_relation')->get();


   foreach ($art_artist_details as $artists_relationn)
     {
        echo $artists_relationn->category;

        foreach ($art_artist_details as $artists_relationn){

              echo $artists_relationn->artists_relation->phone_no;
          }             
 }
```

The problem is that the Foreach loops only once but it gives an error when the second loop reaches the  `echo $artists_relationn->artists_relation->phone_no;`

after that it gives the following error "Trying to get property of non-object"
I have done my research but its like i have reached a dead end. please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you  don't need second loop, so it's enough to use:

```
$art_artist_details = approved_projects_model::with('artists_relation')->get();

foreach ($art_artist_details as $artists_relationn)
{
   echo $artists_relationn->category;
   echo $artists_relationn->artists_relation->phone_no;                     
}
```

but looking at your relationship you are probably using wrong foreign key.

You should define relationship this way:

```
public function artists_relation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\artists_details_model', 'artist_id');
}
```

And in addition you should make sure you have always matching record in artists_relation - if not, instead of

```
echo $artists_relationn->artists_relation->phone_no;
```

you should use:

```
echo $artists_relationn->artists_relation ? $artists_relationn->artists_relation->phone_no : 'none';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin the problem was the foreign key and the reason why my code is not following good code practices is because i was focusing on making the code work. but now it works thanks.